# How do you insert a key and value into a pre-existing dictionary

Tags: python

I would like to insert `"three": 3` into the following nested dictionary:

```
dict = {
    "test": {
        "one": 1
        "two": 2
    }
}
```

I tried `dict.update({"test": {"three": 3}})` but this doesnt work as it only updates the top level dictionary.

The solution to this is to apply `.update()` onto the specific dictionary

```
test['test'].update({"three": 3})
```

or onto the specific value

```
test['test']['three'] = "3"
```

Comment: Please don't include text as images, update your question including the source code as text in your question.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to from my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.update()` doesn't merge nested dictionaries, it just updates the top-level dictionary. You need to do:

```
test['test']['three'] = "3"
```

or

```
add = {"three": "3"}
test['test'].update(add)
```